# Delete all nodes where the taxonomy term matches a given value

Tags: 7, database

I have a content type (example_content_type) with 3 3 fields: title, body, and pks_type. pks_type is a taxonomy term select list field. and 'pks_type'has 2 terms:

- Type1, tid = 1
- Type2, tid = 2

I have 150 nodes using those taxonomy terms. Now I need to delete all nodes from 'example_content_type' except last 5 nodes, where the taxonomy term ID is 1.

How can I achieve this with `db_delete()`?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! To answer it, we need more details. For example, since that table doesn't seem used from Drupal, which database fields does it contain? In particular, does it contain the node ID and the taxonomy term ID, or just one of them?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, please see my question, I trying to explain my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) as it allows you to pick exactly the nodes you want based on a wide range of criterias (check the documentation [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) and a tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-drupals-entityfieldquery/)) and you can exclude the last 5 nodes by adjusting the range of the query itself.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->propertyCondition('bundle', 'example_content_type')
      ->fieldCondition('field_pks_type', 'tid', '1')
      ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
      ->range(5);

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  node_delete_multiple($nids);
}
```

In this case the query will find all entities of type *node* and bundle *example_content_type*, with the *pks_type tid 1* and retrieve them newest first starting with the 6th entry (and thus ignoring the 5 last/most recently entered nodes).

*(I added the code for deleting the nodes, though it might be good to print a list of nodes to be deleted or back up the db before actually using the code.)*

---

**Edit 1:**

Just now saw you asked about using `db_delete()`. In this case you can still use the code above to retrieve the ids of the nodes you need to delete and delete them with `db_delete()` rather than [`node_delete_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete_multiple/7.x) - however unless you have a specific use case where you need to use `db_delete()` it is better using the appropriate delete hooks as those will also clear corresponding field tables and allow other modules to react to the node's deletion.

```
if (isset($result['node'])) {
    $nids = array_keys($result['node']);

    foreach($nids as $nid) {
        db_delete('node')
        ->condition('nid', $nid)
        ->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Zuzuesque, your solution is working. just little modify your "->entityCondition('bundle', 'example_content_type')" to "->propertyCondition('type', 'example_content_type')". and then working well... thanx again :)

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is the "except last 5" constraint. I suggest the following solution:

db_select the nodes' nids that you don't want to delete in the first step, like

`$savenids = select nid from node where -whatever- limit 5`.

Then db_delete the rest of the nodes like

`delete from node where -whatever- and nid not in $savenids`.

The -whatever- terms strongly depend on your field setup, take a look at your tables for that.